# Android Studio AdMob template doesn't work out of the box

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So my new Android Studio projects doesn't work (btw i have not written ANYTHING i just created a new project from this template and started the Emulator just to notice it crashed and gave me 12 errors) the line i seem to have difficulties with is:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
```

I checked and the build.gradle file includes this line under dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
```

Please help, honestly i think it's pretty sh*t of Google to make a template that simply doesn't work, they should know how to write a functional application inside of their own IDE right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Admob App ID in the **manifest** file?

```
 <application>
    <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
</application>
```

If you don't do that your app will be crushed, so you will have to add it.

**edit:** your import is wrong you must replace it with:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
```

Comment: I found it, but the name is "android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP" with the value true, and i changed it to what you wrote. Doesn't work with either :(.

Comment: can you write the error that showing to you with android studio when you run it?

Comment: well in the Build Output window it says "cannot find symbol class InterstitialAd" like 5 times, and then another error with "method does not override or implement a method..." but i think i can fix that myself.

Comment: replace your import to this code: `import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;`

Comment: interstitial.InterstitialAd works to import, it can be resolved but it does not have the necessary functions. It gives me errors like "cannot resolve method 'setAdUnitId' in 'InterstitialAd'", other methods that cannot be resolved are setAdListener, isLoaded and loadAd

Comment: Also i noticed that getAdUnitId works for instance, so it seems to be readOnly?

Comment: you can learn more from here [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)